# ng-repeat, do not update table after data was updated?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that is populating with `ng-repeat`, and I also have navigation button that change table data. Before I had custom filter on the data in html file, like so:

```
ng-repeat="car in carList | filter:tableFilter"
```

Even so it worked, it slowed my website, a lot. So now I am updating my table data in my controller. But there is another problem, `ng-repeat` do not want to update. So no matter how much I will update my data, the table will be still the same.

**How can I fix that?**

Here is my `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="car in sortedCarList">
    ....
```

Here is my nav-bar:

```
<section class="tab" ng-controller="TablePanelCtrl as panel">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills car-navigation">
          <li ng-class="{ active: panel.isSelected(1)}">
            <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1); initCarList(1); resetActiveRow(); formattedTable(2); hideTypeBox()">Sort by Reviews</a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{ active: panel.isSelected(2)}">
            <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(2); initCarList(2); resetActiveRow() formattedTable(2); hideTypeBox()">Sort by Rating</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

`initCarList()` changes the data according to tab number.

`formattedTable()` filters table data according to filter values that can be changes by user.

UPDATE:

my formatting function:

```
$scope.formattedTable = function(index){
    $scope.initCarList(index);
    $scope.sortedCarList = [];
    var carlistLength = $scope.carList.length;
    for (var i=0;i<carlistLength;i++){  // just check every row if values passes user requirements 
        var rowBool = $scope.tableFilter($scope.carList[i]);
        if (rowBool){
            $scope.sortedCarList.push($scope.carList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's your JS? We can't debug what we can't see.

Comment: the markup is also required, various directives creates child scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with cerbrus that we need to see a bit more of your code, I'll take a stab in the dark : you call `formattedTable(2)` in both tabs, which means that your filtering never changes.

Comment: that was just my mistake why writing this question

Comment: Glad I could be of some help ! Also not you are doing initCarList twice (once in your ng-click, once in formattedTable() ).